# Compare the same column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I need some help solving this problem.
I have the following table (dbo.Users) ordered in a descending way by ID:

```
ID |  UserID | Status | Time   |
3     9200       2      2013-05-03
2     9200       1      2013-05-02
1     9200       1      2013-05-01
```

I want to check if the top two rows have different values for Status column, and if so, I want to get the entire first row.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Comment: Hi. I think the topic is not clear enough. May I suggest something different? - **"How to compare the top 2 rows returning the top one if there are mismatches?"** or  **"How to compare the top 2 rows?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by "top two rows" you mean ordered by id descending, then:

```
select u.*
from (select top 1 u.*
      from dbo.Users u
      order by u.id desc
     ) u
where u.status <> (select top 1 u2.status
                   from dbo.Users u2
                   where u2.id < u.id
                   order by u2.id desc
                  );
```

The first subquery gets the top row.  The second subquery determines whether the status is equal to the status in the second row.

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I wanted. If I wanted to compare more columns other than Status, following the same logic, could I just add an AND/OR after the WHERE statement?

Comment: @Dias . . . Ask another question, with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a computed row_number according to the USERID

```
SELECT ID
    ,Userid
    ,STATUS
    ,TIME
    ,ROW_Number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY UserID
        OVER BY TIME DESC
        ) AS rn
FROM TABLE
```

The row number is partitioned by the userid, so the row number will be restarted for each userID. It is sorted according to TIME, but you could change that if you wanted. If you want to filter this, you'll need to wrap it in an outer query

```
select * from (SELECT ID
    ,Userid
    ,STATUS
    ,TIME
    ,ROW_Number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY UserID
        ,STATUS OVER BY TIME DESC
        ) AS rn
FROM TABLE
)sub
where sub.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ID is unique, you can use the following code:

```
WITH cte 
 AS (SELECT TOP 2 * 
     FROM   dbo.users 
     ORDER  BY id DESC) 
SELECT cte1.* 
FROM   cte cte1 
   INNER JOIN cte AS cte2 
           ON cte1.id > cte2.id 
WHERE  cte1.status != cte2.status
```

If you have a bigger table, then this would be faster compared to the other queries, too.